# mysql workbench seems to have a max record limit

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

i have been using mysql workbench to input records manually. i thought it interesting that last night when i finished i managed to input exactly 1000 rows. to my surprise today i inputted approx 80 fresh records and hit apply the count remained ad 1000 rows. is this some sort of default setting? whats the fix?

Comment: How do you know the count remained at 1000 rows? Did you run a query like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table`? Or you just click the table in workbench and load them there?

Comment: most probably just the workbench preference setting https://superuser.com/questions/240291/how-to-remove-1000-row-limit-in-mysql-workbench-queries#:~:text=.4.0.828)-,On%20the%20menu%20bar%20visit%20Edit%20%2D%3E%20Preferences%20.,decrease%20the%20Limit%20Rows%20Count.

Answer (score 0):

Look for 'limit rows' in the Query menu.

Alternatively use the drop down in the query toolbar:

[image]

Comment: can i write a query to extend that? i dont see limit rows anywhere on the dashboard

Comment: Have you looked in the Query menu? (fourth along at the top)